# BOM query combining components on 1 row

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to build a BOM query that shows all components on 1 row rather than split out each on it's own row.  All Parent items have either 2 or 3 components.  The structure is:

```
select * from product;
```

| Code | Component | Quantity | Line number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | PartA | 1 | 0 |
| Product1 | PartB | 1 | 1 |
| Product1 | PartC | 2 | 2 |
| Product2 | PartA | 1 | 0 |
| Product2 | PartD | 1 | 1 |

And I am hoping to achieve a table with 1 row per parent items and columns showing Components and Quantities ordered by Line Number:

| Code | Component1 | Quantity1 | Component2 | Quantity2 | Component3 | Quantity3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | PartA | 1 | PartB | 1 | PartC | 2 |
| Product2 | PartA | 1 | PartD | 1 |  |  |

I tried 3 sub-queries to select Component where LineNum=0, then LineNum=1, LineNum=2

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.[CODE], 
(SELECT I.COMPONENT WHERE I.LINENUM=0), 
(SELECT I.COMPONENT WHERE I.LINENUM=1), 
(SELECT I.COMPONENT WHERE I.LINENUM=2) 
FROM I
```

but it still returned 3 rows per "parent"

| Code | Component1 | Quantity1 | Component2 | Quantity2 | Component3 | Quantity3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | PartA | 1 |  |  |  |  |
| Product1 |  |  | PartB | 1 |  |  |
| Product1 |  |  |  |  | PartC | 2 |
| Product2 | PartA | 1 |  |  |  |  |
| Product2 |  |  | PartD | 1 |  |  |
| Product2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need pivoting. For multi-column pivot, easiest is to use condition case statement with aggregate.

```
select p.Code,
       Component1 = max(case when rn = 1 then Component end),
       Quantity1  = max(case when rn = 1 then Quantity end),
       Component2 = max(case when rn = 2 then Component end),
       Quantity2  = max(case when rn = 2 then Quantity end),
       Component3 = max(case when rn = 3 then Component end),
       Quantity3  = max(case when rn = 3 then Quantity end)       
from
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Code order by Component)
    from   product
) p
group by p.Code
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f343850f29a6878ba388dbca04b6155)

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick!!